# Odd blurry circle on safari iphone html5 videos

Tags: css, iphone, video, safari

This weird circle appears on certain websites (picture bellow), on iphone > safari.
On the safari console i could detect that it is because of the video autoplay, but i am not able to erase it.

I've already tried (with no luck):

1- `erase the controls tag`

2- `video::-webkit-media-controls { display:none !important; }`

Thanks-a-bunch

[image]

This is a clip of the code:

```
<div style="position: relative;">
        <div style="position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px; right: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-image: none; background-size: cover; background-position: 50% 50%; background-repeat: no-repeat;">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" style="margin: auto; position: absolute; z-index: -1; top: 50%; left: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%); visibility: visible; width: 855px; height: auto;"><source src="video_5.mp4" type="video/mp4"></video>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hi @Paulie_D i included a piece of the code :)

Answer (score 0):

Couple years late, but this worked for me:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button { display: none; }
```